# SQLite vs Memory

Tags: iphone, sqlite, memory, performance

I have a situation with my app.

Suppose I have 6 users, each user can have up to 9 score entries (i.e score 1000 points at 8:00pm with gold collected 3, silver 4 etc etc), say score per stage and 9 stages.

All these scores are being taken from an API call, so it can update with an interval of 3+minutes.

- Operations I need to do on this data is

  - find the nearest min, max record from stage 4.
  - and some more operations like add or subtract two scores etc

All these 6 users, and their score records are already in database, being updated in needed after the API call.

Now my questions is :

Is this a better way for such kind of data (data of scores here) to keep all the data for all the 6 users in memory in NSArray or NSDictionary, and find min and max in that array by a min-max algorithm.

OR

It should be taken from Database by a query like " WHERE score<=200 " AND " WHERE score >=200", in short, 2 database queries which return nearest min and max record each, and not keeping all the data in memory.

What we are focusing on is speed, and memory usage both. The point is, Would a DB call be fast and efficient to find min and max OR a search for min,max in an Array of all the records from DB.
All records can be 6users * 9scores for each = 54.
Update time for records can be 3+ minutes.
Frequency of finding min max for certain values are high.

Please ask, if any more details are required.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with such a small amount of data that I wouldn't imagine it would be worth worrying about. Do whichever method makes your development process easiest!

**Edit:**

If I had a lot of data (hundreds of competitors) I'd use SQLite. You can do queries like the following:

```
SELECT MIN(`score`) FROM `T_SCORE` WHERE `stage` = '4';
```

That way you can let the database handle doing the calculation for you, so you never have to fetch all the results.

My SQL-fu isn't the most awesome, but I think you can also do this:

```
SELECT `stage`, MIN(`score`) AS min, MAX(`score`) AS max FROM `T_SCORE` GROUP BY `stage`
```

That would do all the calculations in one single query.

Comment: Thanx Amorya ! 

Suppose I have a reasonable amount of data then what would u choose, DB or keeping that data in NSArras/NSDictionaries ?